# Linux run service on boot - up as soon as possible

Tags: boot, systemd, raspberry-pi

Here is my service:

```
# This service will run in parallel with other services
# create ... mouselogger.service
# /etc/systemd/system

[Unit]
Description=MojeUre boot init display

[Service]
Type=simple
# RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/mojeure/scripts/MojeUreBoot.py
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=mojeureboot.service
```

I want to run it right after I plug-in power into my rasppbery pi.

How should I re-edit this service? Script is in Python, basicaly it outputs some text on LCD screen which is connected to RPI.

Currently have this code in service, but still service starts after network:

```
[Unit]
Description=MojeUre boot init display
Before=network-pre.target
Wants=network-pre.target

[Service]
Type=simple
# RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/mojeure/scripts/MojeUre.py
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
# WantedBy=basic.target
Alias=mojeureboot.service
WantedBy=network.target

    enter code here
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your script need to work propertly
you have banch of targets to use in `WantedBy` directive. I'd use `basic.target`, or `network.target` (if you need data from network to be displayed)

Comment: Currently it tooks 25sec to run this service from boot, any chance to speed up boot service at startup?

Comment: try to run  systemd-analyze plot > bootchart.svg and look what is starting so slow and is it possible to disable/change dependencies of smth